# Atualizar registros vinculados com Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Por exemplo eu tenho uma classe pessoa e toda pessoa pode ter um cônjuge caso ela queira (Opcional).

Vamos supor que eu tenha duas pessoas cadastradas no banco:

> PessoaId: 1, Nome: João, PessoaConjugeId = null
>
> PessoaId: 2, Nome: Maria, PessoaConjugeId = null

Eu quero que quando atualizar o joão assim:

> PessoaId: 1, Nome: João, PessoaConjugeId = 2

Automaticamente a maria fique assim:

> PessoaId: 2, Nome: Maria, PessoaConjugeId = 1

Depois de um tempo o João pode voltar a ser solteiro e voltar para o estado inicial:

> PessoaId: 1, Nome: João, PessoaConjugeId = null

Com isso Maria também deve voltar ao estado inicial:

> PessoaId: 2, Nome: Maria, PessoaConjugeId = null

*Gostaria de saber se o entity framework possui alguma configuração que automatize esse processo de atualização, se não existir qual seria o melhor caminho para realizar esse processo de atualização?*

```
//Classe Pessoa
public class PessoaModel
{
    public int? PessoaId { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    public int? PessoaConjugeId { get; set; }
    public virtual PessoaModel PessoaConjuge { get; set; }    
}

//Fluent API
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<UsuarioModel>()
        .HasOptional(c => c.UsuarioConjuge)
        .WithMany()
        .HasForeignKey(c => c.UsuarioConjugeId);
}

//Metodo que atualiza
public UsuarioModel Atualizar(UsuarioModel model)
{
    MeuSistemaContext db = new MeuSistemaContext();

    if (db.Entry(model).State == EntityState.Detached)
    {
        db.Set<UsuarioModel>().Attach(model);
    }

    db.Entry(model).State = EntityState.Modified;
    db.SaveChanges();
    return model;
}
```

Comment: Me parece um erro de modelagem. Se uma tabela depende da atualização da outra você deveria usar uma tabela intermediária pra isto.

Comment: Consegue postar um código de exemplo de como eu deveria fazer, estava aqui agora mesmo tentando fazer e notei que quando eu faço: var lstPessoa = db.TbPessoa.ToList(); e cliko no + da lstPessoa pelo visual studio para navegar nas propriedades ele trava o visual studio, acredito que deva estar em loop infinito.

Comment: Obrigado, eu agradeço. Enquanto isso vou vendo aqui se chego a algum lugar rsrs

Answer (score 0):

Como disse o [LINQ](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/18246/linq), realmente é um erro na modelagem e você deveria ter uma tabela intermediária.

Em um sistema comum, sem o EF, você poderia criar uma trigger no update da tabela Pessoa para alterar o cônjuge.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda.